# How do I remove the arrows from the breadcrumbs?

Tags: breadcrumbs

How do I remove ">>" from the breadcrumbs?

I need to remove those characters because in my site, the breadcrumbs appear like in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

This is the code that generates the breadcrumbs.

```
$temp = "</a>" . $title . "</a></div>"; 
$breadcrumb = str_replace("</a></div>", $temp, $breadcrumb); 
print($breadcrumb);
```

Comment: It seems a strange way to generate breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 2):

You can override [theme_breadcrumb()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7) function in your theme. As mentioned in the below code.

```
function yourthemename_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    // Provide a navigational heading to give context for breadcrumb links to
    // screen-reader users. Make the heading invisible with .element-invisible.
    $output = '<h2 class="element-invisible">' . t('You are here') . '</h2>';

    $output .= '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
    return $output;
  }
}
```

Just write above code in your template.php and change *>>* to whatever you want.

Comment: I edit the "page.tpl.php" located in "sites / all / themes / Bartik / templates"
Here's the content that generates brudcrumb

<code><!-- /.section, /#breadcrumb -->
    <?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
      <div id="breadcrumb">
   <?php 
      $temp = "</a>" . $title . "</a></div>"; 
      $breadcrumb = str_replace("</a></div>", $temp, $breadcrumb); 
      print($breadcrumb);  
      ?>
   </div><div class="clearfix"></div><code>
it does not work, I have not succeeded in obtain a result. thank you for more details please.

I use drupal 7

Comment: @Honline - Your code is NOT the same as the answer code.  Please try again using the code in the answer provided.

Comment: i try with the code in the answer. it does not work, the breadcrumb disapear :(

Comment: In your `template.php` file, not in your `page.tpl.php`?  Don't forget you'll need to clear your theme registry (cache) for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @Honline Did you replace yourthemename with the name of your theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can fully customize how you'd like to have your breadcrumps, see http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7

Comment: thank you for your response,
I did not find how to do it since. I am not an expert in drupal7.
I only want to remove the ">>" and thank you for your help :)